# Convert date in text format to datetime format in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-parsing

I have a client supplied file that is loaded in to our SQL Server database. This file contains text based date values i.e. (05102010) and I need to read them from a db column and convert them to a normal date time value = '2010-05-10 00:00:00.000' as part of a clean-up process.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way by using

```
CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(Column,4) + left(Column,4))
```

example

```
declare @s char(8)
select  @s = '05102010'
select CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@s,4) + left(@s,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime,  RIGHT(YourColumn,4)
                       +LEFT(YourColumn,4)
           ) AS ProperDateTime
    FROM...
```

working example:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (StringDate char(8))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('05102010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('03182010')

SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime,  RIGHT(StringDate,4)
                       +LEFT(StringDate,4)
           ) AS ProperDateTime
    FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
ProperDateTime
-----------------------
2010-05-10 00:00:00.000
2010-03-18 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
        SUBSTRING(col, 1, 2)
        + '/' + SUBSTRING(col, 3, 2)
        + '/' + SUBSTRING(col, 5, 4))
```