# Convert DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD at SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008, one report have text fields which takes data as DD/MM/YYYY as input, but at query i would like it to covert as YYYY-MM-DD.

I have tried with below code but could not succeed.

```
Declare @a varchar(20)= '27/03/2014'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(@a as DATE),126)
```

Output required as

```
2014-03-27
```

Comment: try to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805512/convert-date-in-text-format-to-datetime-format-in-t-sql

Comment: it failed i have just tried Declare @b char(8)= '27032014'
select CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@b,4) + left(@b,4)) and it resulted as "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." @Yohanes Khosiawan

Comment: try to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466100/conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of

Comment: its a same as available in other threads.. cast and convert functions. my problem is input data at text field is like 27/04/2014.. when it come down as parameter to query, i need it to convert to yyyy-mm-dd. @Yohanes Khosiawan

Comment: actually you can eliminate that `/` character..
and you can use that `set dateformat dmy` to avoid the `out-of-range value` error

Comment: does it work..? or still has another err message?

Comment: @Yohanes Khosiawan .. it worked as Set dateformat dmy
Declare @a varchar(10)= '27/03/2014'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST('27/03/2014' AS DATE),126)   thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS Report Date format Change use for this concept.

create table **az(id integer,Dob varchar(20));**

```
insert into az values(1, '25/03/2014')
insert into az values(2, '26/03/2014')
insert into az values(3, '27/03/2014')
insert into az values(4, '28/03/2014')
select * from az
```

Use this Line for your  Textbox Field Expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Dob.Value),"",Mid(Fields!Dob.Value,7,4) + "-" + 
Mid(Fields!Dob.Value,4,2) + "-" + Left(Fields!Dob.Value,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DATECOL VARCHAR(13) = '25/01/2015'

-- Date Format
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@DATECOL,4) + '-' + LEFT(RIGHT(@DATECOL,7),2) + '-' + LEFT(@DATECOL,2) AS DATE)

-- Varchar format
SELECT RIGHT(@DATECOL,4) + '-' + LEFT(RIGHT(@DATECOL,7),2) + '-' + LEFT(@DATECOL,2)
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4ba9/2)**